# How to grant a group to another group in Redshift

Tags: permissions, role, redshift

I am trying to build a matrix of roles to dynamically change priorities for our users. In other database I would be doing something like:

```
create role role1;
create role role2;
grant role role1 to role2;
```

In Redshift I found the concept of groups, but it looks like it is not possible to assign groups to other groups, is there any solution to handle this?

Comment: Maybe you could expand on this question a little? As it is, it's a bit unclear. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: I tried to rephrase it